# ContentDocumentFeed vs FeedItem

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, visual-workflow, contentdocument

**TL;DR:** Question about the `ContentDocumentFeed` object and the `FeedItem` object: which is the one I want to use when accessing files uploaded through the Salesforce Files Sync tool? I can see that both have access to the base64 file data, but I don't know which is the correct object to use.

Full explanation: I'm interning for a company and they have a scanner to upload JPEG images to a shared drive. From there, the images are copied to a Salesforce Files Sync folder.

I need to be able to process each image file as a new attachment to a custom object (I have Notes & Attachments enabled for the object already). The scanned images are product registration cards that need to have the info listed on them entered in as fields for the custom objects.

I understand how to do that part: make a trigger that acts on `ContentDocument` after insert, and generate a new custom object record with a new `Attachment` for that object, setting the attachment's base64 content to that of the uploaded file, for each `ContentDocument` found. From there, I just have to make a VisualForce page to show the new custom objects along side the attachment they have associated with them, and all of this will be controlled by a workflow.

But I don't know whether to use `ContentDocumentFeed` or `FeedItem` to access the file data. Because of the limit on CRM document uploads, I'd prefer to maintain that the files do transition to attachments, rather than link each `ContentDocument` to each new object, since then, as attachments, they'd be able to remain on the server, and the `ContentDocuments` can be permanently deleted afterward.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was `ContentVersion`.